# Paginate table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, dynamics-crm

We are working with Customer Portal in Dynamics 365. I have to use a pagination plugin with existant data in the HTML table.

The current code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here there are more than one hundred of records. I have to include a pagination area in the bottom to allow users to paginate the table.

While digging on internet I saw there are several plugins to achieve pagination but their data source are often an object array. Here I have to paginate specific rows (`<tr>`).

I have tried so far:

```
rows = [];
$('table:first tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
    rows.push(row);
});
recordsPerPage = 20;
pages = Math.ceil(rows.length / recordsPerPage);
```

Before I write a bunch of lines I would like to know if someone knows about a plugin to paginate only what `rows` contain.

For example I could use plugin **[Pagination.js](http://pagination.js.org/)** like the [documentation](http://pagination.js.org/docs/index.html) says:

```
dataSource: function(done){
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        result.push(rows[i]);
    }
    done(result);
}
```

Right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to check out [datatables.js](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: I would suggest try using different framework to build your HTML and then in turn pulling data and displaying it. For example Knockout.js is a good Framework to look into. Here is the [Link](https://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html)
Here is one of my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnkUser/975ncawv/599) I worked on it has Paging and most of the necessary stuff.

Comment: @Aron, I know datatables, but they don't allow an already built table, or HTML rows.

Comment: @AnkUser, I can't just change the framework. Already solved anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of researching I found a posible solution with [Pagination.js](http://pagination.js.org).

```js
let rows = []
$('table tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
 return rows.push(row);
});

$('#pagination').pagination({
    dataSource: rows,
    pageSize: 1,
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        $('tbody').html(data);
    }
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#pagination {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#pagination ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.1.4/pagination.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data-container">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1: Row 1</td>
      <td>Column 2: Row 1</td>
      <td>Column 3: Row 1</td>
      <td>Column 4: Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1: Row 2</td>
      <td>Column 2: Row 2</td>
      <td>Column 3: Row 2</td>
      <td>Column 4: Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1: Row 3</td>
      <td>Column 2: Row 3</td>
      <td>Column 3: Row 3</td>
      <td>Column 4: Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Still, I don't make this work since the `.pagination()` method is not working even if loaded the script with `$.getScript('url', function() {});` or `document.createElement('script')` but I think this is a different issue and post...