# JQuery Pagination Plugin Callback function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do pagination using Pagination Plugin https://pagination.js.org/ , on page click function i'm not able to call the appropriate content and I don't want to create the content dynamically so how to make pagination for already created content. I didn't get how to implement the code in `handlerPaginationClick()`. I have attached sample code below which is not working, kindly help me out.

HTMl

```
code here


<table class="table table-bordered" id="pagination">
    <tr>
      <th>Head1</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
      <th>Head3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Adrees 1</td>
      <td>employee 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Adrees 2</td>
      <td>employee 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Adrees 3</td>
      <td>employee 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 4</td>
      <td>Adrees 4</td>
      <td>employee 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 5</td>
      <td>Adrees 5</td>
      <td>employee 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 6</td>
      <td>Adrees 6</td>
      <td>employee 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 7</td>
      <td>Adrees 7</td>
      <td>employee 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 8</td>
      <td>Adrees 8</td>
      <td>employee 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 9</td>
      <td>Adrees 9</td>
      <td>employee 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 10</td>
      <td>Adrees 10</td>
      <td>employee 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 11</td>
      <td>Adrees 12</td>
      <td>employee 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paginate">
      <td>Name 13</td>
      <td>Adrees 13</td>
      <td>emloyee 13</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="page-nav"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function(){
    $("#page-nav").pagination({
        dataSource: function(done){
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
                result.push(i);
            }
            done(result);
         },
         pageSize: 1,
         callback : handlePaginationClick
    });
});
    function handlePaginationClick(new_page_index, pagination_container) {
        $(".paginate").hide().slice(3).show();

    }
```

});

Comment: `"I don't want to create the content dynamically"` - why not? That's pretty much how pagination works. Side note: your `<table>` contains invalid HTML; it should follow the structure of `table > tbody > tr`, *not* `table > tr`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Yes ,I forgot <tbody> and <thead> . Actually im doing news website, in that i have used more than 30 Bootstrap cards .I'm new to this concept so I dont know which one would be better . I refereed website and found this approach. could you please help me to find solution.

Comment: Where does your HTML come from? Is there a news feed or something similar?

Comment: I got clear now . I'm using dynamic method with json data and pagination also . for pagination i'm using TWBSpagination plugin . in this is there any option like itemPerPage? its displaying only one item so how can i display more than one item on a page.

Comment: Have a read of the documentation; if you're still stuck then you should post a new question as it's a different plugin.

Comment: @NishaBasha did you found solution? I have the same question and I do not know how to do it...

Comment: Maybe if found solution, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540408/paginate-table-rows-with-jquery